# how to make ajax submit redirect?

Tags: php, ajax

in php, if i submit via ajax, how to redirect to other page when result comes back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it in javascript;  after you get the result back `window.location = "newpage.php"`

Comment: is it not appropriate to put navigation logic in client side?

Comment: yeah, but with ajax you can't do it any other way

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX to redirect pages with Javascript, you're losing all the benefits of AJAX, consider simplifying your system so that it just submits its data with a regular POST.

If you're doing it asynchronously because you want the page to redirect on some specific event that the user has no control over,  **don't**. Instead do something similar to StackOverflow - pop up a little status bar at the top or bottom (or side) of the page with a link for the user to click when they're ready.